# php MySQLi File upload

Tags: php, mysqli

Dear friends I am unable to fine whats wrong with my codes, kindly look into this please.
When i post the page it do not upload the file, even $_FILES["file"]["name"] comes blank.

Since i am using the technique of include once, the add category files is called as a module, therefore the form action='index.php?addcategory' is just calling the same file again.

```
// FILE UPLOAD
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}

// FILE UPLOAD

$displayname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['displayname']);
$categoryname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['categoryname']);
$meta = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['meta']);
//$file = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['file']);
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

if ($displayname == null || $categoryname == null || $file == null )
{
$msg = '<div class="msg error"><span>ERROR:</span> Please fill in all required fields!</div>';

} else {
$insert_row = $con->query("INSERT INTO category (displayname, categoryname, meta, icon) 
VALUES($displayname, $categoryname, $meta, $file)");

$sql="INSERT INTO category (displayname, categoryname, meta, icon)
VALUES ('$displayname', '$categoryname', '$meta', '$file')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  $msg ='<div class="msg error"><span>ERROR:</span> Category Added Failed</div>';

} else {


$msg ='<div class="msg success">Category Added Success</div>';

}}}
echo $msg;
?>



<form action='index.php?addcategory' enctype="multipart/form-data" method=”post”>
<input name="addcategory" type="hidden" value="addcategory">
<div class="formbox"><label>Category Display Name</label>
<input name="displayname" type="text"></div>
<div class="formbox"><label>Short Name</label>
<input name="categoryname" type="text"></div>
<div class="formbox formbox_full"><label>Meta Description</label>
<textarea name="meta"></textarea></div>
<div class="formbox"><label>Category Name</label>
<input name="file" id="file" type="file"></div>
<div class="formbox formbox_full"><input type="submit" value="Add Category" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have smart/curly quotes in `method=”post”` that's why. Replace it with `method="post"`

Comment: if i do     method="post"     then it do not post at all, the URL shows no variable as well

Comment: You have 2 INSERT queries, I'm confused. Remove the first one. Plus, why are you using GET?

Comment: @fred-ii- you steal my comment. i am confused. too.

Comment: after the fred suggestion are you able to upload??

Comment: didn't work :(   I changed GET to POST and removed the double query

Comment: @user1231648 I've undeleted my answer to modify it. Reload to see the changes. If that doesn't work, I may delete it once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have smart/curly quotes in `method=”post”` that's part of the problem.

Replace it with `method="post"`

You also need to use quotes around your VALUES variables

```
VALUES ('$displayname', '$categoryname', '$meta', '$file')
```

You also have 2 queries to INSERT. Remove the first one being:

```
$insert_row = $con->query("INSERT INTO category ...
```

I don't know why you have that, use the second one.

You're also using `$_GET` when using a POST form method; use `$_POST` where you have `$_GET` and then modify your form's action to `action=''` since you're executing everything inside the same page, and naming your submit button to `name="submit"` -
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Category" />` while wrapping your entire PHP/SQL inside a conditional statement, such as:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  // PHP/SQL

}
```

You also have 3x `}}}` the 3rd one seems to be extra, remove it.

being here

```
}}} <= 
echo $msg;
```

change it to

```
}}
echo $msg;
```

if you don't have anything else above your first line of code.

---

**EDIT:** (upload folder)

I also noticed folder name differences, `upload` and `img` in:

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

if the intended folder is `upload`, then change `img` to `upload`.

If the intended folder is `img`, then change all `upload` to `img`.

Make sure that you are running your form and PHP/SQL from the root of your server. If not, then you may need to re-adjust `upload/` to `../upload/` or  `../../upload/` (*for example*)
or `../img/` <= if that is the folder's upload name, and depending how many sub-levels you need to go down to, while making sure the folder has proper write permissions set.

Comment: `$displayname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['displayname']);
$categoryname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['categoryname']);` is that right he using POST in the form.

Comment: its working now, showing Upload: sample1.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 16.6337890625 kB
Temp file: C:\Windows\Temp\phpC3BC.tmp
Stored in: img/sample1.jpg
--------
but how to upload thew file?

Comment: @user1231648 You have `Stored in: img/sample1.jpg` yet have `if (file_exists("upload/"` and `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];` change `upload` to `img` unless the intended folder is in fact `upload`?

Comment: @user1231648 I've made an edit to make it a bit clearer. Reload my answer and look under `EDIT: (upload folder)`

Answer (score 0):

These are what came to my mind when I saw your code :

1. Please add close tag form
2. Please use var_dump($_POST); to see whether your data are being sent succesfully.
3. If the point number 2 return "Null" please review and re-write your form's attribute. Copy & paste form attribute sometimes lead to not-working form because of the different encoding.

Hope those helps.

Comment: how to use var_dump($_POST) to check

Comment: @user1231648 are you able to upload anything after fred suggestion??

Comment: simply type "var_dump($_POST);". It will return the "raw" version of your $_POST variables at that page.